# Allow all characters except # and $ in XSD

Tags: regex, xsd, special-characters

We have a requirement to allow all the characters (including special chars) except #, $ and space to an XSD element.

I’ve tried the regex as `[^$#\s]*` but didn’t work. Can you please help with the resolution as I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: How did it not work?  I just tried that and it woks as expected.

Comment: Is there other white space like CR LF in the data that is supposed to be allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your regex in a XSD and it works as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO53903548" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO53903548" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SpecialString2">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[^$#\s]*" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Will quite happily validate the below, but fail on $,# or space

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.SO53903548">
 <SpecialString2>thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydog@THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPEDOVERTHELAZYDOG!~`@%^&amp;*()-_+=</SpecialString2>
</ns0:Root>
```